# У меня есть код который должен считать количество написанных сообщений за час но пишет ошибку 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_chat_messages'

Tags: python, aiogram

Он должен считать сколько написали сообщений за последний час в канале

````
async def count_messages_handler(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = -1001919013571
    try:
        messages = await bot.get_chat_messages(chat_id, limit=50000)
        messages_in_hour = 0
        hour_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
        for msg in messages:
            if msg.date > hour_ago:
                messages_in_hour += 1
        await message.reply(f"Количество сообщений в канале за последний час: {messages_in_hour}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
        await message.reply("Произошла ошибка при подсчете сообщений.")``` пишет ошибку ```Bot' object has no attribute 'get_chat_messages'```
````

Comment: Такого метода попросту нет.